# data not displaying while executing action support vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using action support to autopopulate fields when the first field is filled up. But data is not getting displayed. Please help

Apex class -

```
public with sharing class RFPController{

    public RFP__c accounts;
        public Custom_Package__c del;
        public List < Custom_Package__c > addattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > attendeeList {get;set;}
        public Integer totalCount {get;set;}
        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delAttendees {get;set;}
        public Boolean isRerender{get;set;}
        public String S {get;set;}
        private List<Custom_Package__c>  acc {get;set;}

        public RFPController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

                isRerender = false;
                accounts =  (RFP__c )controller.getRecord();
                String S = 'Select id, Name, Market__c, State__c, First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c from Custom_Package__c WHERE Name = :S';
                //totalCount = attendeeList.size();
                attendeeList  = Database.Query(S);
                attendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c >();
                for(integer i=0;i<1;i++){ 
                attendeeList .add(new Custom_Package__c ());
                }
                delattendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();
                delattendees = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();

                accounts.Rep_Name__c= Userinfo.getuserId();
        }

        public void addRow() {
                isRerender = true;
               addattendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();
                attendeeList.add(new Custom_Package__c ());
        }

        public void fetchRelatedAccountData(){
        system.debug('@@@@' + S);
                acc = new List<Custom_Package__c>();
                acc = [SELECT Name, Market__c, State__c,Circulation__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c,Space_Unit__c FROM Custom_Package__c WHERE Name = :S];

                system.debug('@@@@@@' + acc);

        }


        public void deleteRow() {

                rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
                System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + rowIndex);
                System.debug('rowm to be deleted ' + attendeeList[rowIndex]);
                del = attendeeList.remove(rowIndex);
                delattendeeList.add(del);

        }
}
```

VF Page -

```
<apex:page standardController="RFP__c" extensions="RFPController" sidebar="false">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">

      </apex:outputText>      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Child RFP Details" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable"  var="acc" value="{!attendeeList}" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">
             <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandLink value="Copy" reRender="pb" onclick="testMe(event)"/>
          </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package Input" >
            <apex:inputText value="{!S}">
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchRelatedAccountData}" rerender="thetable" />
            </apex:inputtext>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" style="width:300px" id="cp1"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Market" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Market__c}" id="mar1"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="State" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.State__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="First Issue" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.First_Issue__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Last Issue" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Last_Issue__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Circulation" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Circulation__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Space Unit" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Space_Unit__c }"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Space Discount">
          <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Space_Discount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Per Unit Open Rate">
          <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">

              <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <!-- </apex:pageblockSection> -->
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Row" reRender="pb"/>  

      <script>
      function testMe(event){
               var current= event.target.parentElement.id;              
               index = Number(current.split(":thetable:")[1].split(":")[0]);
               if(index==0) 
               return;
    var tbody_tr = document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var trLength= tbody_tr.length;
    var sTD1= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable:'+(index-1)+':cp1').value;
    document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable:'+index+':cp1').value = sTD1;
}   
      </script>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that your `fetchRelatedAccountData` method updates the controller's `acc` field but the table you are presenting is based on the controller's `attendeeList` field. (The Visualforce `var` happens to also be called `acc`).

Modify the `fetchRelatedAccountData` method to update `attendeeList` instead.

Comment: Hi Keith.. Thanks for the help..I have another problem..as from the code you will know that i am using action:support for autopopulate fileds. Suppose i fill the first field and i added another row.. How to get the action:support should fire for which rowindex...please help

Comment: @Sid Unclear to me why it matters and you only have one S value in your controller too. Best if you post a separate question explaining in detail what you are trying to achieve in the different rows.